# Change of variables with the sign function $v = |u|^{p-1}\mathrm{sign}\, u$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations, inverse-function, change-of-variable

If $v = |u|^{p-1}\mathrm{sign}\, u$, how can we explicitly write $u$ as a function of $u$?

If we didn't have the sign function there, we could just write 
$$u = v^{m},$$
with $m= 1/(p-1)$.
The motivation is the following. In the PDE 
$$(|u|^{p-2}u)_t - \mathrm{div}(|Du|^{p-2}Du)=0, \quad 1 < p < \infty,$$
can we use a change of variables to rewrite it in the form 
$$v_t - \mathrm{div}(|Dv^m|^{p-2}Dv^m)=0$$
for some $m$?

Answer (score 1):

OK, we have that:

$v = |u|^{p-1}\mathrm{sign}\, u$

From here, it's obvious that $u$ and $v$ have the same sign.    $(*)$

It's worth noting that: $sign (u) = u / |u|$, for $u \ne 0$

1) If $p=1$ we obviously cannot solve for u, so we have no inverse function.
Why? Well, because $v=1$ always (for any $u$).

2) If $p \ne 1$ we get:

2.1.) $u \ge 0$
In this case $v = u^{(p-1)}$ and so: $u = v^{1/(p-1)}$

2.2.) $u \lt 0$
In this case we get:
$v = (-u)^{(p-1)} \cdot (-1)$
$-v = (-u)^{(p-1)}$
$-u = (-v)^{1/(p-1)}$
$u = - ( (-v)^{1/(p-1)} )$

So using $(*)$ we can write 2.1.) and 2.2.) as follows:

$ u =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  v ^ {1/(p-1)}  & \mbox{if } v \geq 0 \\
  - ( (-v) ^ {1/(p-1)} ) & \mbox{if } v \lt 0
 \end{array}
\right. $

And now, we can luckily unify the two cases/branches:

$ u = sign(v) \cdot |v|^{1/(p-1)}$

This formula is true for $p \ne 1$ and for all values of $v$.

Comment: Thanks. So we write $v=|u|^{p-2}u$. How does this help in finding $u$ as a function of $v$?

Comment: It doesn't help much. You need to look at two cases $u \gt 0$ and $u \lt 0$ and you solve this for u. That's the best you can do here, I think.

Comment: What is p btw? Is it natural, integer, rational or real?

Comment: In that case you have $u = v^{1/(p-1)}$ if $u >0$ and $u =  -v^{1/(p-1)}$ if $u <0$. Is it correct to write, summing up, $u = v |v|^{1/(p-1) -1}$?

Comment: $p \in \mathbb R_+$

Comment: OK... in that case if $p=1$ you don't have inverse function, it seems. Let me extend this answer.

Comment: Ok, assume $p>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any way to write that in a more compact way using the absolute value?

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated my question to add the motivation for it. Could you also address it please?

Comment: Oh, it's been ages since I've seen any PDEs, sorry :)

Comment: You need to check my calculations, I think they are OK (I checked them 3 times) but I am not 100% sure, it's 2 AM here :)